# Mac magic keyboard F keys not working

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

After updating Yosemite on an iMac 2011 for some reason my F keys on my [magic keyboard](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLA22LL/A/magic-keyboard-us-english) stopped working.  When I researched the only question I was able to find was "[Function keys Magic Keyboard not bound correctly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222518/function-keys-magic-keyboard-not-bound-correctly)" but that is for Mavericks.

I've gone into settings and tried `Change Keyboard Type..` but that hasn't changed the beeping behavior when I click an F key.

I've tried both wired and wireless connections and I've removed the keyboard from the Bluetooth.

When searching I found [Why are my top-row keyboard buttons not working on Mac Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139359/why-are-my-top-row-keyboard-buttons-not-working-on-mac-lion) but I dont have all those options:

[image]

Diving deeper I found [Top row of keyboard isn't working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166294/top-row-of-keyboard-isnt-working) so I unplugged my iMac and let it sit for an hour.  Logged in and re-connected the keyboard and the same issue occurs.

**Mac system specs:**

- OS: Yosemite
- Version: 10.10.5
- iMac 27-inch, Mid 2011

App Store says no more updates available. How can I get my F keys back?

Comment: Same problem here. Been on the apple support call for 1 hour now and they still haven't found anything to help me. I'll just go back to the store and exchange it for a wired one.... nevermind, they don't sell them anymore... -_-

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using a magic keyboard 2 on High Sierra (iMac late 2013). I tried several programs such as Spark or Function flip, even tried Applescript. The only solution for me was installing Karabiner-Elements https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/. There is a version for Yosemite - click on the arrow next to download and you get all the options.
[image]